# What is the motivation for sequence invariant?

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, contest-math

I am working on q16 of chapter 1 in Arthur Engel's book: Problem Solving Strategies.

**Question:**

Each term in a sequence $1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ...$ starting with the seventh is the sum of the last $6$ terms mod $10$. Prove that the sequence $..., 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ...$ never occurs.

**Official solution:**

The invariant is $f(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6) = 2a_1 + 4a_2 + 6a_3 + 8a_4 + 10a_5 + 12a_6 \quad(\text{mod } 10)$. We have $f(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0) = 4$ but $f(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1) = 8$, hence $0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1$ can never occur.

**My translation/understanding of the solution:**

We want to find some property that holds in $1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0$ and is preserved throughout the sequence but not in $0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1$, thus implying the latter can never occur.

First we compute a few of the terms in the sequence using the recurrence $a_{i+1} = 2a_i - a_{i-6}$,

$$1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 5, 0, 9, 8, 5, 0, 7, 9, 8, 7, 6, 7, 4, 1, 3, 8, 9$$

but an invariant is not immediately obvious.

We then note that $1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0$ shifted one right is $0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1$, hence the former has more terms to the left and the latter has more terms to the right. If we take the weighted sum of the first $6$ elements and weight them more if they are on the left we would be assigning a larger value to $1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0$ indicating that it has more non-zero terms on the left. More concretely:

$$f(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6) = w_1a_1 + w_2a_2 + w_3a_3 + w_4a_4 + w_5a_5 + w_6a_6$$

where $w_1 > w_2 > w_3 > w_4 > w_5 > w_6$.

However, how do we choose the weights (trial and error?), and why should $f \text{ mod } 10$ be invariant? (I know how to prove it is invariant, but don't understand why one would intuitively think of it as an invariant without being told beforehand.)

Essentially, I am trying to answer: how could I have come up with the invariant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that we want to come up with an invariant $f(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_6) = w_1 a_1 + w_2 a_2 + \dots + w_6 a_6$. Our first priority should be making sure that it *is* an invariant.

If we compute the coefficients of $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_6$ in $f(a_2, a_3, \dots, a_6, a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_6)$, those coefficients are going to be $(w_6, w_1 + w_6, w_2 + w_6, \dots, w_5 + w_6)$. Now let's set these equal to $(w_1, w_2, \dots, w_6)$.

First, we get $w_1 = w_6$; then, $w_2 = w_1 + w_6 = 2w_1$. Then $w_3 = w_2 + w_6 = 3w_1$ and so on until $w_6 = 6w_1$.

We have $w_1 = w_6 = 6w_1$, so $5w_1 = 0$. Since we're working modulo $10$, we want $w_1$ to be an even number, and so we might as well pick $w_1 = 2$. The rest of the invariant is filled in by substitution.

This also explains why the problem is about working modulo $10$ to begin with (or alternatively why it's a $6$-term recurrence); we have to have a nontrivial solution to $5w_1 = 0$ here.

Comment: I see how one could have come up with the specific weights now, thanks for that! Is my reasoning about deducing the general form of the invariant sound (i.e. using the fact that $1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0$ right shifted equals $0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1$, so we should weight leftward positions higher)? You weight the leftward positions less, but I feel like we should be able to do it both ways.

Comment: I have some doubts about that argument for the following reason: we're working modulo $10$. So we can't actually say that some positions have "higher" weights, because no value modulo $10$ is "higher" or "lower" than another. We can certainly argue that the even positions should be weighted *differently* from the odd positions, and that would come up if we had a choice of invariants - in this case, we don't.

Comment: Yes makes sense. Sounds obvious reading it aloud. Thank you

Comment: Hm, might want to clarify that the "set coefficients equal to each other" is a form of wishful thinking. IE It's possible for those 2 $f$ values to equal each other without the coefficients being identical.

Comment: @CalvinLin I think the thinking that the $f$ values might stay the same at every step *without* the coefficients being equal is considerably more wishful! (In particular, if we want an invariant that works for every initial condition, then the coefficients must be equal.)